# Form Disabling Color in the Top Unsafe Area

Tags: swiftui, ios17

I have been attempting to add some color to the top of the screen near the notch. I seem to have run into a problem with the color not displaying when used with a **Form**.

I tried using List and VStack--List also doesn't display the green color while VStack does work, but destroys the text formatting. I tried using a ZStack above the Color.green line but this didn't seem to have any impact and possibly not necessary.

This first struct below works fine displaying the title at the top with green background.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { g in
                Color.green
                    .frame(height: g.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)                
               
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Title")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the struct below I added an empty form which causes the color to not be displayed (adding text to the form doesn't change anything).

So I am wondering if I left something out and if there is a work-around to fix this.
Thanks for looking!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            GeometryReader { g in
                Color.green
                    .frame(height: g.safeAreaInsets.top, alignment: .top)
                    .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
                
                Form {
                    
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                Text("Title")
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently your `GeometryReader` encloses the `Form`.
You could try having the `GeometryReader {...}` first (ie move the `}` right after it) then the `Form{...}`.
 Note you need a `NavigationStack`
 for the `.toolbar`. Alternatively move the `GeometryReader` outside the `VStack`

Comment: Sorry, this code is actually down several levels from ContentView and the navigationStack

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned in my comment? Also to be more useful, show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue at the level you describe, see: [Minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I have the proper color but there is a large empty space below the title block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something different using `toolbarBackground`, as
shown in this example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Text("testing")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Title")
                }
            }
            .toolbarBackground(Color.green, for: .navigationBar)
            .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```